# MySQL: Corruption of an index tree: table `innodb_change_buffer` index `CLUST_IND`

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

mysql crashed, and I cannot start mysql server, the err log :

```
2023-10-08T06:22:30.311765Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2023-10-08T06:22:30.311875Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.31/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.31'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew
2023-10-08T06:22:32.242519Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Corruption of an index tree: table `innodb_change_buffer` index `CLUST_IND`, father ptr page no 1974, child page no 1072
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; 1-byte offsets; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0000d433; asc    3;;
 1: len 1; hex 00; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 00045d0c; asc   ] ;;
 3: len 16; hex 000700010c0f02fd0021860300048000; asc          !      ;;
 4: len 18; hex 4138303037392d52454134312d3237373341; asc REA41-2773A;;
 5: len 4; hex 84377a9d; asc  7z ;;
2023-10-08T06:22:32.243237Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: n_owned: 0; heap_no: 2; next rec: 555
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; 1-byte offsets; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0000d433; asc    3;;
 1: len 1; hex 00; asc  ;;
 2: len 4; hex 000440cc; asc   @ ;;
 3: len 16; hex 000000010c0f02fd0021860300048000; asc          !      ;;
 4: len 19; hex 4145434138303133352d534554474d31334252; asc SETGM13BR;;
 5: len 4; hex 8438ec23; asc  8 #;;
 6: len 4; hex 000007b6; asc     ;;
2023-10-08T06:22:32.243894Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: n_owned: 0; heap_no: 122; next rec: 10707
2023-10-08T06:22:32.243904Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: You should dump + drop + reimport the table to fix the corruption. If the crash happens at database startup. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery. Then dump + drop + reimport.
2023-10-08 14:22:32 0x70000af8f000  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 123145486397440 in file ut0ut.cc line 918
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

---

I tried innodb_force_recovery=3 to start the server and drop some corrupted tables, it seems worked, the server now can started, but it keeps restart itself and show same error log above

I couldn't find any table with name 'innodb_change_buffer'. So what's the error means, and what should I do?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.  View profile, please.